# How to improve react redux performance?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a component a table with many rows (50-100). There is an ability to edit lines and type there text. All lines are stored in redux store. I update store on every keypress and it takes about 1-1.5sec before the typed character is appeared in the textarea. Every line is a separate component.

The approximate structure is bellow (but of course it's much more complex)

```
@connect(store => {
  return {
    phrases: store.phrases
  };
})

export default class TableContainer extends React.Component {
 handlePhraseUpdate = value => {
  // update redux store here  
};

render() {
  return this.props.phrases.map((phrase, index) => {
    return (
      <Phrase
        phrase={phrase}
        onPhraseUpdate={this.handlePhraseUpdate}
      />
    )
  })
 }
}
```

How can I refactor this code?

Comment: You can save the current value in the component's state and only update redux with the final outcome on submit.

Comment: @Daniel yep I tried to do so, it gets better but I have another issue of updating phrases when they're changed in the store and not directly in the component. That was the only reason I started using global store

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When dealing with large collections in Redux, it's best to factor you code so that the fewest components re-render when an item in the collection changes.

In your current implementation, when a `Phrase` is updated, the `TableContainer` receives a whole new array of phrases and will re-render all of them, even though only one has changed.

By connecting the `Phrase` component and looking up the individual phrase for each one will result in just the single row updating when the phrase is updated.

It is best to use an `id` of some kind on the values, for example:

```
@connect((store, ownProps) => {
    return {
      phrase: store.phrases[ownProps.id]
    }
  })

export default class Phrase extends React.Component {
  handlePhraseUpdate = value => {
    // update redux store here  
  }

  render() {
    const { phrase } = this.props
    // render phrase
  }
}

@connect(store => {
  return {
    // this could also be stored rather than calculated each time
    phrases: store.phrases.map(p => p.id) 
  };
})

export default class TableContainer extends React.Component {
  render() {

    return this.props.phrases.map((id) => {
      return (
        <Phrase key={id} id={id} />
      );
    });
  }
}
```

If you don't have an `id` you can use the index in the array:

```
@connect((store, ownProps) => {
    return {
      phrase: store.phrases[ownProps.index]
    }
  })

export default class Phrase extends React.Component {
  handlePhraseUpdate = value => {
    // update redux store here  
  }

  render() {
    const { phrase } = this.props
    // render phrase
  }
}

@connect(store => {
  return {
    phraseCount: store.phrases.length
  };
})

export default class TableContainer extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const phrases = []
    let index = 0

    for (let index = 0; index < this.props.phraseCount; index++) {
      phrases.push(<Phrase key={index} index={index} />)
    }

    return (
      <div>
        { phrases }
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your performance issues are not related to redux, but to ReactJS itself.

This is because whenever you update your global object, all your rows are re-rendered. You should re-render only the row that the user is updating.

You can have control over a component render, using the [shouldComponentUpdate](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) method.

For example, you want to update the component only if its internal state has changed.